# ¿Cómo correr un test con linea de comando gradle y serenity.conf?

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, build.gradle, serenity-bdd

Tengo un archivo de configuracion de serenity con environments definidos (default, dev, stagin y preprod). ¿Cuál sería el comando para poder correr el test con alguno de estos ambientes mediante consola? He intentando utilizar `gradle clean verify -Denvironment=preprod` pero no me funciona. Solo quiero correr el de una URL en especifico.
¿Alguno sabe el equivalente de `mvn clean verify -Denvironment=env` pero utilizando solamente gradle.

**Estructura de mi oproyecto.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi archivo de serenity.conf**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi clase desde donde llamo la URL según el la linea de comando**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi archivo build.gradle**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Ya he solucionado mi inconveniente. Solo tenia que colocar en mi archivo build.gradle `systemProperty 'environment', System.properties['environment']`  y ejecutar el comando `gradle clean test -Denvironment = dev`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]